# Python list input 2 same words, how to print it only once

Tags: python, list

Hi first time posting here, I am trying to make a list that only prints an input once. For example if the user enters:
car
dog
dog
house
car
then your program should display:
car
dog
house

```
wordlist = []
while True:
  word  = (input("Enter a word (blank to quit): "))
  wordlist.append(word)
  if word == wordlist:
   wordlist.remove(word)
  if word == "":
     break

for word in wordlist:
    print(word)
```

I also tried

```
if word == wordlist:
    wordlist[-1]
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: `word in wordlist` should work, provided you also replace `wordlist.remove(word)` with `continue`, and put `wordlist.append(word)` after the check, not before. `word == wordlist` is comparing a string to a list, which probably won't ever return `True` in your code. Also, your indentation is inconsistent - I'd recommend using an IDE that keeps it consistent, otherwise you'll run into all kinds of issues.

Comment: `if word not in wordlist: wordlist.append(word)` is what you want right after you read the word in.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python tutorial list", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  Very briefly, you're comparing a single word -- a string -- to the list as a whole.  These can *never* be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order of words does not matter use `set`

```
wordlist = set()
while True:
    word  = (input("Enter a word (blank to quit): "))
    if word == "":
        break
    wordlist.add(word)

for word in wordlist:
    print(word)
```

If order of insertion of word matters append the list with condition

```
wordlist = []
while True:
    word  = (input("Enter a word (blank to quit): "))
    if word == "":
        break
    if word not in wordlist:
        wordlist.append(word)

for word in wordlist:
    print(word)
```

If you want to keep the duplicates but just want to remove while printing

```
for word in set(wordlist):
    print(word)
```

If orders need to be maintained while printing

```
visited=set()
for word in wordlist:
    if word not in visited:
        print(word)
        visited.add(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [49]: words = 'car dog dog house car'.split()                                           

In [50]: from collections import OrderedDict                                               

In [51]: word_dict = OrderedDict()                                                         

In [52]: for word in words: 
    ...:     word_dict[word] = None 
    ...:                                                                                   

In [53]: for word in word_dict: 
    ...:     print(word) 
    ...:                                                                                   
car
dog
house
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
wordlist = []
while True:
  word  = (input("Enter a word (blank to quit): "))
  if not word:
    break
  elif word not in wordlist:
    wordlist.append(word)

for word in wordlist:
    print(word)
```